# How to Export data from Excel as same styles in columns

Tags: javascript, excel

I want to Export excel data which is containing words styles in columns or rows as same text color, strokes, text weight, background color like everything should be uploaded into my database, especially in salesforce through Visualforce page or Lwc Component.

I tried import a Excel js library, but i couldn't giving result as expected.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have try to search a little on that and this is what I discovered.

To export Excel data with word styles and upload it to Salesforce (Visualforce or LWC), follow these steps:

1. Retrieve data from the database using Apex (Visualforce) or
   JavaScript (LWC).
2. Format the data with desired word styles (text color, strokes, etc.).
3. Use a library like ExcelJS to generate the Excel file.
4. Create an Excel workbook and worksheet.
5. Populate the worksheet with formatted data and apply styles.
6. Export the Excel file for download (Visualforce: provide download link, LWC: use lightning-file-download component).
7. Upload the downloaded file to Salesforce using appropriate API or Apex controller, such as ContentVersion/ContentDocument.